# MySQL - Select last rows of LEFT JOIN column based on the fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a mobile chat web application and I have stuck in a problem. Coming straight to the issue, I have a screen which displays messages list from all users (like WhatsApp). I want to display the last message sent or received between the users in the list (as in the screenshot below). My current query extracts the message from the 1st row for all users right now. That's not what I want.

**Little more brief details of what is happening**

As you can see in `messages` table, the fields `msg_from` and `msg_to` represents the sender and the receiver respectively. In my data, the messages are transferred between user 1 & 8 and user 1 & 11. For user 1 & 8 the last record fetched should be record 9 which has `msg_message` `Are you there?` and similarly, for user 1 & 11 the last record to be fetched would be record 10 which has `msg_message` `Would you like to join?`. But currently, for all users the record getting fetched is the 1st record with message `How are you?`. What changes should my query have to get the desired result? Please have a look at the fiddle below.

Fiddle Here: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xnh4jiUb8rDLFHpL2gWHrM/0)

[image: WhatsApp Screenshot]

Comment: @TheImpaler Please check the DB fiddle I gave above already.. It has the sample data and I have already briefly mentioned the expected result with the screenshot... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xnh4jiUb8rDLFHpL2gWHrM/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned a lot from researching in order to solve this. When grouping, groupBy will take the first row of non-grouped columns (suck as msg_message), so we may order it when joining with the help of a subquery, just like this:

```
SELECT swp_by, swp_to, msg_from, msg_to, mem_fname, mem_lname, mem_last_activity, msg_message, GREATEST(MAX(msg_time), swipes.swp_date) as msgdate, COUNT(msg_id) as msgcnt FROM swipes

LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT * FROM messages order by msg_time desc  -- this is the magic, we use this subquery to order before grouping       
) 
messages ON 
((
     messages.msg_from = swipes.swp_by 
     AND messages.msg_to = swipes.swp_to) 
     OR (messages.msg_from = swipes.swp_to 
     AND messages.msg_to = swipes.swp_by
))
```

solution is in your fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xnh4jiUb8rDLFHpL2gWHrM/5

[image]

I think I got expected output

Comment: Wow.. All that was needed was adding a simple sub query only and I couldn't figure that out.. maybe because I didn't sleep a minute in the last 24 hours... Feeling silly to miss out on such a simple solution!!!! You saved my day brother.. thanks :D

Comment: However, do I really need to use `SELECT *` here??

Comment: Also, you said you learned a lot from solving the issue. I think you should not have deleted that. If it was a learning experience for both of us, I am happy I was able to put up a logical question. My question deserves an up vote ;) ?

Comment: I do not know a way to order a table while joining it without a select subquery. I know it seems subpar, maybe an expert in MySQL will come by and show us a way so we both may feel silly c: I tend to be mocked for making enphasis in such matters, but since you ask for it, I edited the learning part as requested c:

Comment: Hehe... I am waiting for that too.. However, for now, what you did seems to be a life saver. Although, it's been 2 hours I posted this question and no "such" mysql expert bothered to show up till now for help.. I wish someone does so quick.. hehe.. ;)

Comment: man I ran to some sort of problem here. I see that it's perfectly working on the Fiddle and I even rechecked it multiple times myself but when I replace the code with mine one it's just giving the same result inside the while loop. That should just not be possible. What the hell is happening here bro.. Please help!!!! Also, in PhpMyAdmin also it's not working and returning the same result. What can be the problem?

Comment: I meet you in SQL chat

Comment: Your chatroom link? I think I already sent you a text.. Please have a look in your chat room.